# Why in react-admin GMapINput is not recognized?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, dataprovider

I am trying to use GMapInput from @fusionworks/ra-google-maps-input within react-admin,

It works with [sample](https://github.com/FusionWorks/react-admin-google-maps/tree/master/example) project 
But breaks when doing npm install into own project,

> Something went wrong A client error occurred and your request couldn't
>   be completed. Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either
>   the context or props of "Connect(t)". Either wrap the root component
>   in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(t)".

```
in Connect(t)
in Unknown (at App.js:60)
in div (created by FormInput)
in FormInput (created by SimpleFormView)
in div (created by ForwardRef(CardContent))
in ForwardRef(CardContent) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)) (created by CardContentInner)
in CardContentInner (created by SimpleFormView)
in form (created by SimpleFormView)
in SimpleFormView (created by FormView)
in FormView (created by ReactFinalForm)
in ReactFinalForm (created by FormWithRedirect)
in FormWithRedirect (created by SimpleForm)
in SimpleForm (at App.js:57)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(Card))
in ForwardRef(Card) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)) (created by EditView)
in div (created by EditView)
in div (created by EditView)
in EditView (created by Edit)
in Edit (at App.js:56)
in EntityEdit (created by WithPermissions)
in WithPermissions (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (created by ResourceRoutes)
in Switch (created by ResourceRoutes)
in ResourceRoutes (created by Resource)
in Resource (at App.js:34)
in Route (created by RoutesWithLayout)
in Switch (created by RoutesWithLayout)
in RoutesWithLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
in div (created by Layout)
in main (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in Layout (created by WithStyles(Layout))
in WithStyles(Layout) (created by Context.Consumer)
in withRouter(WithStyles(Layout)) (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by LayoutWithTheme)
in ThemeProvider (created by LayoutWithTheme)
in LayoutWithTheme (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (created by CoreAdminRouter)
in Switch (created by CoreAdminRouter)
in div (created by CoreAdminRouter)
in CoreAdminRouter (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (created by AdminUI)
in Switch (created by AdminUI)
in AdminUI (created by Admin)
in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
in ConnectedRouter (created by Context.Consumer)
in ConnectedRouterWithContext (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by AdminContext)
in TranslationProvider (created by AdminContext)
in Provider (created by AdminContext)
in AdminContext (created by Admin)
in Admin (at App.js:33)
in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

Comment: Check your react-admin version. You may be using 3.x while the latest GMapInput uses ra 2.9.

Comment: Anyone has an alternative to this component? having the same error and I need to use google API in my react-admin project